# VS Studio Code cant run GDB on helloworld.cpp on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gdb

Successfully downloaded and installed Visual Studio Code for Ubuntu and went thru the config process OK including setup the GDB. Then I add a break point on the main procedure as told by intro tutorial. When I try to 'step over' (F10) I get this error message in the Debug output console:

> ERROR: Unexpected GDB output from command "-exec-next". Cannot enable
> the TUI when the interpreter is 'mi'

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was a problem that I had a hook-next defined in ~/.gdbinit.